# how to read pins states, put them in a bitmask together and print it to the serial?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm trying to read 14 inputs using Arduino, put their values inside one variable (uint16_t type) and print the result on the serial monitor.
How to do it?

EDIT:
FOR NOW THE CODE HERE PRINTS ONLY 7 BITS, WHY IS THAT?

I tried:

```
#define CLOWN_1 (49)
#define CLOWN_2 (48)
#define CLOWN_3 (47)
#define CLOWN_4 (46)
#define CLOWN_5 (45)
#define CLOWN_6 (44)
#define CLOWN_7 (43)
#define CLOWN_8 (42)
#define CLOWN_9 (41)
#define CLOWN_10 (40)
#define CLOWN_11 (39)
#define CLOWN_12 (38)
#define CLOWN_13 (37)
#define CLOWN_14 (36)



uint16_t clowns_mask = 0b00000000000000;

uint8_t clowns_pins[] = {CLOWN_1, CLOWN_2, CLOWN_3, CLOWN_4, CLOWN_5, CLOWN_6, CLOWN_7, CLOWN_8, CLOWN_9, CLOWN_10, CLOWN_11, CLOWN_12, CLOWN_13, CLOWN_14};

uint16_t get_clowns_state() {
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        clowns_mask |= (uint16_t)(digitalRead(clowns_pins[i]) << (uint16_t)i);
        // bitWrite(clowns_mask, i + 1, digitalRead(clowns_pins[i]));
    }
    return clowns_mask;
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(get_clowns_state(), BIN);
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205218/discussion-on-question-by-kd-technology-how-to-read-pins-states-put-them-in-a-b).

Comment: I would say you found the problem. You should check and upvote Evg’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a global variable `clowns_mask` which you do not reset to zero in `get_clowns_state`. Each time you call `get_clowns_state`, you set bits in it, but you never clear them up. Use a local variable:

```
uint16_t get_clowns_state() {
    uint16_t clowns_mask = 0;
    for (int i = 13; i >= 0; --i) {
        clowns_mask <<= 1;
        clowns_mask |= (digitalRead(clowns_pins[i]) == HIGH);
    }
    return clowns_mask;
}
```

2. To print leading zeros, use a simple loop:

```
uint16_t state = get_clowns_state();
for (uint16_t mask = (uint16_t)1 << 15; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    Serial.print((state & mask) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

3. Depending on a circuit, you might need to [enable](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) built-in pull-up resistors:

```
void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; ++i)
        pinMode(clowns_pins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
}
```

Comment: It prints constantly "0000000001000000"

Comment: @KDTechnology, the error is somewhere else, not in this code.

Comment: I changed the declaration in setup() to INPUT_PULLUP and now it almost works!
They only problem is that the values that change inside the clowns_mask doesn't seem to fit the inputs... and not all of them work.

Comment: @KDTechnology, I can't give any specific answer to this, sorry. Just check you connections and pin numbers.

Comment: So I disconnected everything from the Arduino to see that the INPUT_PULLUP really takes all the pins up, but for some reason, something is running over pins 47-44 and I get "0011111111000011"